# How to force ImageJ to close all its windows without close event error?

Tags: java, imagej

I am writing a Java application for image analysis which at one point opens `ImageJ` with

```
ImageJ ij = new ImageJ();
```

and also opens a Windows containing an `ImagePlus`.

Now, whenever one closes `ImageJ` first, the `ImagePlus` will **not close** when pushing the close button. The other way around works, however in both cases an exception is thrown after closing `ImageJ`:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1288)
    at java.awt.Window.doDispose(Window.java:1209)
    at java.awt.Window.dispose(Window.java:1147)
    at ij.ImageJ.run(ImageJ.java:784)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
    at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:56)
    at java.awt.AWTEvent.<init>(AWTEvent.java:337)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.<init>(InvocationEvent.java:285)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.<init>(InvocationEvent.java:174)
    at sun.awt.X11.XBaseMenuWindow.dispose(XBaseMenuWindow.java:907)
    ...
```

I don't know whether it is related as it happens in both cases.

Any suggestions on how to force `ImageJ` to close all its windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The exception

This happens when using OpenJDK 7 on Linux. The exception is [fixed in Java 8](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/user-interface-bug-in-imagej-fiji-tt5009927.html).

Also: note that that exception is not the actual cause of the quitting issue you are seeing.

#### The disposal problem

ImageJ 1.x's application disposal is a convoluted mess. (See [this news post](http://imagej.net/2014-07-11_-_Fiji_won%27t_quit!) for some technical discussion.) It was really intended primarily to run as a standalone application, and is mostly tested with the `exitWhenQuitting` flag set to true such that the JVM shuts down upon closure of the main window. So it is not surprising that using ImageJ in a different fashion results in hanging image windows.

I have tested various workarounds—e.g.:

```java
ij.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(final WindowEvent e) {
        // dispose all image windows
        for (final int id : WindowManager.getIDList()) {
            final ImagePlus imp = WindowManager.getImage(id);
            if (imp == null) continue;
            final ImageWindow win = imp.getWindow();
            if (win != null) win.dispose();
        }
        // dispose all other ImageJ windows
        for (final Window w : WindowManager.getAllNonImageWindows()) {
            w.dispose();
        }
    }
});
```

But none of them work as one might hope. It cost me weeks of development and experimentation to make quitting work as we wanted in [ImageJ2](http://imagej.net/ImageJ2), according to the news posted linked above.

Here is some code using ImageJ2 that *almost* behaves the way you want:

```java
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import net.imagej.ImageJ;

public class IJDispose {

  public static void main(final String... args) {
    final ImageJ ij = new ImageJ();
    ij.ui().showUI();

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello");
    final JButton b = new JButton("Close ImageJ");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        ij.getContext().dispose();
      }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(b);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

After launching it, press Shift+B to open the Blobs sample image. Then click the "Close ImageJ" button from the non-ImageJ frame. You'll see that the ImageJ main window *and* the image window dispose as desired (using [this code from ImageJ Legacy](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-legacy/blob/imagej-legacy-0.17.4/src/main/java/net/imagej/legacy/IJ1Helper.java#L207-L227)).

However, there are (at least) three problems:

1. This example does not hook up the `ij.getContext().dispose()` call to the actual ImageJ1 UI window closing event. And doing that would not be trivial (I say without having dug deeply in this code recently).
2. After disposing ImageJ, as well as the extra `JFrame`, the JVM is *supposed* to shut down. We put a lot of effort into making it do so, actually. But it actually doesn't with the current version of ImageJ, presumably due to some undisposed resource(s) somewhere. This is a bug.
3. Clicking the X on the main ImageJ window shuts down the entire JVM, because ImageJ1's `exitWhenQuitting` flag gets [set to true](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-legacy/blob/imagej-legacy-0.17.4/src/main/java/net/imagej/legacy/IJ1Helper.java#L139-L150). You could toggle it back to false yourself, but this is actually tricky due to class loading issues relating to the fact that ImageJ2 patches ImageJ1 at runtime using Javassist.

The next question is: How badly do you really need this to work?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It is true that with Java 8 the error message disappears, but the main problem still remains. If one closes ImageJ first, the opened image is unclosable. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Thank you very much for that informative answer. I will probably have a look at ImageJ2 and maybe replace the ImageJ1 stuff. But at least I know that it was not just a coding error.